# How to extract plain text from a DOCX file using the new OOXML support in Apache POI 3.5?

Tags: docx, apache-poi, openxml, xlsx

On September 28, 2009 the [Apache POI project](http://poi.apache.org/) released version 3.5 which officially supports the OOXML formats introduced in Office 2007, like DOCX and XLSX.

Please provide a code sample for extracting a DOCX file's content in plain text, ignoring any styles or formatting.

I am asking this because I have been unable to find any Apache POI examples covering the new OOXML support.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This worked for me. Make sure you add the required jars (upgrade xmlbeans, etc.)

```
public String extractText(InputStream in) throws Exception {
    XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(in);
    XWPFWordExtractor ex = new XWPFWordExtractor(doc);
    String text = ex.getText();
    return text;
}
```

Comment: I noticed that this method doesn't read text from textboxes.

Answer (score 8):

**This is more generic**

POITextExtractor poitex = ExtractorFactory.createExtractor(in);

return poitex.getText();

Comment: I agree. Thank you for a good answer covering more generic text extraction. I wish I could accept both.