# Apache POI - merge two documents - malformed xml generated

Tags: xml, merge, ms-word, apache-poi, docx

I have two .docx documents in byte[] format and I have to merge these two documents into one. The java code runs successfully but I am not able to open the document
I have used the below link to write the merging code -

[Is there any java library (maybe poi?) which allows to merge docx files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494549/is-there-any-java-library-maybe-poi-which-allows-to-merge-docx-files/20732048#20732048)

This works well when I do not have any headers and footers on any of my document.
In case, any one of the two document will have the header or footer, I am not able to open the merged document as the document.xml is malformed or invalid.

I am getting the below error while trying opening the document -

```
Microsoft Office can't open this file because some parts are missing or invalid
Location : Part:/word/document.xml, Line 2, Column 0
```

I had a look at document.xml, it just have the below xml fragment at line 2-

```
<w:document  xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
```

Comment: What about if you try with two really really simple word docs - does that work?

Comment: Yes, I am able to merge two really really simple word documents perfectly.

Comment: Can you work out what about your files is triggering the problem? Perhaps by deleting bits of them until it works?

Comment: yes, I keep removing headers and footers one by one, but it worked only when the documents doesnt have headers and footers at all