# Merging docx with docm

Tags: java, merge, doc

Based on the available code in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494549/is-there-any-java-library-maybe-poi-which-allows-to-merge-docx-files), i was able to merge the content of 2 docx files.

Unfortunately, the code doesn't work properly for docm: **the merged generated docm file has unreadable contents**.

> Word found unreadable content in.....

After choosing 'yes' option, the content is shown correctly.

I saved the current version and did the comparison between the origin and the fixed one by inspecting them internally with ZIP.

**What i found:** docm doesn't seem to work with altChunk, because the fixed version removes it from the document.xml.

But Im not really sure, where does the problem come from ?

Answer (score -1):

I forgot to override the content type of the document.xml. By using [this code](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/docx4j-samples-docx4j/src/main/java/org/docx4j/samples/MacroAdd.java), i was able to generate the docm file with readable content.